# ngAfterViewInit not fired within ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is not being called for a Component that is transcluded into another component using `<ng-content>` like this:

```
<app-container [showContent]="showContentContainer">
    <app-input></app-input>
</app-container>
```

However, it works fine without `<ng-content>`:

```
<app-input *ngIf="showContent"></app-input>
```

The container component is defined as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  template: `
        <ng-container *ngIf="showContent">
              <ng-content></ng-content>
        </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppContainerComponent {
  @Input()
  showContentContainer = false;

  @Input()
  showContent = false;
}
```

The input component is defined as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `<input type=text #inputElem />`
})
export class AppInputComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("inputElem")
  inputElem: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.info("ngAfterViewInit fired!");
    this.inputElem.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

See a live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-vqhjuh

Comment: In your example - if you put a `console.log()` in your app container's `ngOnInit()` you can see that it is being fired. Now this may be due to angular's unidirectional data flow. meaning since the child component can be initialised - it will initialise both components, but not actually render it. In the [lifecycle docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) they gloss over it.

Comment: the problem here is the inconsistency between the behavior of the component when it's in a simple `*ngIf` and when it's included through `<ng-content>` inside an `*ngIf`. The component behaves differently, but it shouldn't -- it has no idea that it's being transcluded.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues at hand here:

1. Child components are instantiated along with the parent component, not when `<ng-content>` is instantiated to include them. (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13921)
2. `ngAfterViewInit` does *not* indicate that the component has been attached to the DOM, just that the view has been instantiated. (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13925)

In this case, the problem can be solved be addressing either one of them:

1. The container directive can be re-written as a structural directive that instantiates the content only when appropriate. See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-mrcokp
2. The input directive can be re-written to react to actually being attached to the DOM. One way to do this is by writing a directive to handle this. See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-sthnbr

In many cases, it's probably appropriate to do both.

However, option #2 is quite easy to handle with a custom directive, which I will include here for completeness:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[attachedToDom],[detachedFromDom]"
})
export class AppDomAttachedDirective implements AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  attachedToDom = new EventEmitter();

  @Output()
  detachedFromDom = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private elemRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) { }

  private wasAttached = false;

  private update() {
    const isAttached = document.contains(this.elemRef.nativeElement);

    if (this.wasAttached !== isAttached) {
      this.wasAttached = isAttached;

      if (isAttached) {
        this.attachedToDom.emit();
      } else {
        this.detachedFromDom.emit();
      }
    }
  }

    ngAfterViewChecked() { this.update(); }
  ngOnDestroy() { this.update(); }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
<input type=text 
       (attachedToDom)="inputElem.focus()"
       #inputElem />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the console of your stackblitz, you see that the event is fired before pressing any button.
I can only think of that everything projected as  will be initialized/constructed where you declare it.

So in your example right between these lines

```
<app-container [showContent]="showContentContainer">
      {{test()}}
      <app-input></app-input>
</app-container>
```

If you add a test function inside the app-container, it will get called immediatly. So `<app-input>` will also be constructed immediatly. Since ngAfterVieWInit will only get called once (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), this is where it will be called already.

adding the following inside `AppInputComponent` is a bit weird however

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('destroy')
}
```

the component will actually be destroyed right away and never initialized again (add constructor or onInit log to check).

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. The fact that the lifecycle hooks are called differently when the sub-component is inside a container vs being just inside the `ngIf` seems really janky. Also I can't really imagine a workaround for this.